# rm /bin/date "operation not permitted"

Tags: sudo

I would like to `sudo rm /bin/date` but I get this message:

```
Password:
override rwxr-xr-x  root/wheel restricted,compressed for /bin/date? y
rm: /bin/date: Operation not permitted
```

Please assume that I am aware of the implications and actually want to do this.

Comment: Which version of macOS are you running?

Comment: Forgive me, but.. knowing the implications without being aware of what's stopping you feels a tad… contra.

Comment: @Tetsujin It might help to have a plan on how to make the system able to boot again, at least :-)

Comment: In recent macOS, /bin/date resides in a read-only filesystem.

Comment: I haven't tested this specific problem with /bin/date, but in order to edit some read-only files on MacOSX you may need to disable System Integrity feature, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/disabling_and_enabling_system_integrity_protection?language=objc

Comment: @Gintaras - it's tougher than that - on Big Sur & up, if you touch anything on the boot volume, you have to re-sign it, or it will just boot to Recovery & do nothing except make you reinstall the OS.